# Anisible pip3 install keeps failing on remote service (No setuptools found in remote host, please install it first)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ansible

I am trying to set up my remote servers and have Anisble install required packages. In my `playbook.yml` everything works fine except when it tries to install `requirments.txt` only on one remote server. It gives me the following error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No setuptools found in remote host, please install it first."}
```

And yes, I **do** have `setuptools` install on the remote host.

```
# pip3 show setuptools
Name: setuptools
Version: 40.4.3
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: pipenv
```

Not sure why it even needs setuptools when I'm using pip3 to install.

Here is my playbook snippet:

```
- name: Install requirements
  pip:
    requirements: /.supv/bridge_modules/requirements.txt
    executable: pip3
```

It seems to work fine on the other remote hosts, just this one is having trouble. I've tried to uninstall setuptools and reinstall, still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ansible needs setuptools to be installed for the version of Python that is being used to run Ansible modules, which, by default, is Python 2.  So you need to run `pip2 install setuptools` or equivalent in order to install setuptools in Python 2.

Comment: How can I set the default to python 3? I have setuptools installed shown above.

Comment: @user10067412: Set `ansible_python_interpreter` to the path to Python 3.

Comment: `ansible-playbook your-playbook-name.yml -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'`

Answer (score 5):

The setuptools package must be installed for both the Ansible Python interpreter and for the version of Python specified by this option.

Which means you have to install setuptools for python2 and python3. Here are my codes before pip install:

```
    - name: install python-setuptools
      package:
        name: python-setuptools
        state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an my ansible role for using pip3 and installing aws-cli

```
---
- name: Install Dependencies
  apt:
    name: ['python3-pip', 'python3-setuptools', 'python3.8', 'python3.8-venv']
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes

- name: Install AWSCLI
  pip:
    name: 'awscli'
    virtualenv_python: /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to upgrade your pip3 first

```
- name: Install and upgrade pip
  pip:
    name: pip
    extra_args: --upgrade
    executable: pip3
```